# Is there any open source library for commodities trading (pricing/risk managment)?

Tags: commodities, library

I think the question is no, as commodities trading requires far more exotic payoffs and hence higher variety of code.

I know that there is a private company known Allegro, one of the main suppliers of such libraries for commodities industry.I also have heard that e.g. EDF Trading uses BlueBird system for exotic calculations.

I would like to know if there is any open source libraries for commodities, similar to OpenGamma/Strata and QuantLib available in finance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know, and I'm in that business. Allegro is a ETRM provider, equivalent to Murex in the banking area, but, as far as I know, they don't provide any library outside their main system (which is not able to deal with any kind of exotic), and definitely nothing open source. Let me know if you find anything, because I would be glad to use it.

Depending on your purpose, you can probably use QuantLib (a colleague of mine uses it) or Strata for commodity pricing, using the equities functions of the library with some workarounds to account for the particularities of commodities, but I don't know if it would be worthy (probably not).